# Return a string from another string based off number and order of specific substrings

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have a string such as

s = "left-left-right-right-left"

and an empty string n = ''

and going from left to right for that string, read the number of lefts and rights that appear, and add an 'a' for every left and 'b' for every right that appears.

In other words a function like

```
def convert(s):
```

would return 'aabba'

I'm thinking along the lines of s.count, but the b's need to be between the a's, and count doesn't tell you where an occurrence of a substring happens.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to replace left by a and right by b. it should work

```
s = "left-left-right-right-left"
s = s.replace("left","a")
s=s.replace("right","b")
s=s.replace("-","")
```

Comment: welcome. if this is what you needed, accept the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution.

```
def convert(s):
    s = s.replace("left", "a")
    s = s.replace("right", "b")
    s = s.replace("-", "")
    return s
```

OR

```
def convert(s):
    return s.replace("left", "a").replace("right", "b").replace("-", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried an recursive solution.

```
def rec_search(s, n):
    if len(s) is 0:
        return n

    if s[-len('left'):] == 'left':
        return rec_search(s[:-len('-left')], n) + 'a'

    return rec_search(s[:-len('-right')], n) + 'b'



print rec_search('left-left-right-right-left', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done using a regular expression `sub()` as follows:

```
import re

s = "left-left-right-right-left"
print re.sub('left|right|-', lambda x: {'left':'a', 'right':'b', '-':''}[x.group(0)], s)
```

Giving you:

```
aabba
```

It works by replacing any `left` `right` or `|` with a function that looks up the replacement text in a dictionary.